# How to find HTML element using file_get_html

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing

using library `simple_html_dom.php`

```
$html = file_get_html($link);
```

In structure like this

```
<div class="ps">    
    <h3>Lorem ipsum 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p>    
    <h3>Lorem ipsum 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 4</p>
    <div class="extras250">
        <div class="boxType3 naSkroty">
            <div class="boxBody shortList">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum 5</h3>                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxType4 wsparcie">
            <div class="boxBody">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum 6</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum 7</p>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


foreach ($html->find('.ps h3') as $naglowek) {
     $info['naglowek'][$i] = $naglowek->plaintext;
     $i++;
     }
```

I'd like to find `<h3>` but only first level (not nested) but foreach finding all of them. How to do this ? I tried

```
foreach ($html->find('.ps > h3') as $naglowek)
```

but not works.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but check once

```
foreach ($html->find('.ps > h3:first') as $naglowek)
```